# Usage of "entrare" in "questa tecnologia entra"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> Pensavo che questa tecnologia sarebbe entrata tra qualche anno.

Is "entrare" usually used like this (= to come in the market)? The sentence does not make sense in English without the place where the technology will enter.

Comment: Il  senso è quello di cominciare : *Entrare* ( 3.)  *Con significato affine a cominciare: entrare in guerra, in azione, il mese appena entrato  etc.* (Treccani)

Comment: Cominciare a cosa? Essere ricercata, essere fabbricata, essere venduta sul mercato?

Comment: Mi suona un po' strano; io lo userei con un complemento, come “entrata in uso”, “in commercio” etc.

Comment: Honestly, this sentence is not great. I doubt many native speakers would use it.

Comment: La frase suona strana anche a me, è come incompleta. Per curiosità, @AlanEvangelista: è un esempio per quale regola? L’uso del condizionale passato?

Comment: @Benedetta Esattamente.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Mi sembra davvero strano che si usi una frase così per spiegare quella regola…

Comment: @Benedetta Penso che l'obiettivo sia spiegare questo uso del condizionale passato (esprimere un evento futuro in una proposizione subordinata, relativo a un evento passato nella proposizione principale) e esercitarsi in la traduzione di questo tempo verbale in inglese (I thought this technology would come in a few years).